# Alternative command for Vi/Cat in Windows 7

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-7-x64

In Unix/Linux we are having vi & cat command to view or edit a file. There are any alternative command to view/edit a file in windows command prompt.

Comment: Why not just install what you are used to?  But out of the box defaults would be notepad and 'type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) is a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.

It includes both `cat` and `vi`.

It is possible to select which parts of Cygwin to install. See [Installing and Updating Cygwin Packages](https://cygwin.com/install.html) for more instructions.

Comment: What are the commands supported by Cygwin @davidpostill. I am facing lot of problems, pls guide.

Comment: `cat` is in the textutils package, `vi` is in the editors package

Answer (score 1):

There is a **edit** on windows but it doesn't work on 64Bit machine. So alternate solution is given below.

Just download vim for windows from [Here](http://www.vim.org) (direct download link), on the installation it will ask if you want to create shortcuts for calling it from the command line. Then you can just vim

Comment: any other commands which support in 32-bit but not in 64-bit Windows OS @LalitJ

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, To view the filename use, `Type filename`